# Use a formula on SQL Server column values and store it in new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to use a formula on a column, what I want is I have a value in a column I want to multiply it by `(100 / SumofColumnValues)` what I succeeded till now is get the Sum of Count

```
select 
    Count(*) as ResponseCount,
    PropertyValue As Answer 
from 
    table 
where 
    Questionid = 42 and formid = 1 
group by 
    propertyvalue
```

This give something like this

```
ResponseCount  Answers
     34        One
     100       Two
```

and then using CTE:

```
With Temp As (
    select 
        PropertyValue As Answers,
        Count(*) As ResponseCount 
    from 
        questionerdetail 
    where 
        Questionid = 42 and formid = 1 
    group by 
        PropertyValue
)
select Sum(ResponseCount) As Total 
from Temp
```

I get

```
Total
 134
```

What I need is

```
ReponseCount  Answer  ResponsePercentage
     34       One       25.37       TheFormula will be 34*(100/134)- (134 is the total sum of responsecount)
     100      Two       74.62       TheFormula Will be 100*(100/134)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or if you want to use analytical functions instead of sub-select:

```
    select 
    Count(*) as ResponseCount,
    PropertyValue As Answer ,
 convert ( dec(28,2) ,Count(*))*100/(sum(count(*)) over ()) as ResponsePercentage
from 
    table 
where 
    Questionid = 42 and formid = 1 
group by 
    propertyvalue
```

(The convert function is SQL Server syntax)

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    Count(*) as ResponseCount,
    PropertyValue As Answer ,
 Count(*)*100/(select count(*) from table ) as ResponsePercentage
from 
    table 
where 
    Questionid = 42 and formid = 1 
group by 
    propertyvalue
```

Comment: this is perfect the only problem im getting is the reponsepercentage is in int so .94 is changed to 0 else everything is just perfect.